# "joining" multiple tables in MySQL and ordering them by date format: 1319744408

Tags: php, mysql, join

I've been trying to get this to work for hours and have tried several options on stackoverflow with no luck. I have seen on here what I thought I would need but just not getting it.
I will give an example of what I think should work but get an error: Column 'date2' in order clause is ambiguous - I know that means date2 is listed in more than one table, which is correct and that's what I want. Anyways, here is how I'd like for it to be:

```
$sql = "SELECT
            *
        FROM
            videos, games, pics
        ORDER BY
            date2 DESC
        LIMIT 10";

mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

videos, games & pics all have a date2 field which I would like to order by for the home page. The date2 field has the date formatted like, 1319744408.

I've tried several things with no luck. Someone please help me.

Comment: What is the common field that makes videos relational to games relational to pics?

Comment: The clue is in the question

Answer (score 3):

It is ambiguous because you have the same field name in three tables but have not specified which of these you are trying to order by (i.e. videos.date2).

You also have the problem that you are currently making a Cartesian join of all records across the tables.  So if you have 100 records in each table, you would end up with 1 million records in your result set (100 * 100 * 100) before applying the limit.  You are probably not intending to sort 1 million rows.

You should specify the join conditions between the tables, be specific about the table and column you want to order by, and probably be specific about the fields you actually need to return in the result set rather than using `SELECT *`.  You also need to make sure you have indexes on all the fields you would use for joins or for ordering so your query can run more efficiently.

If your intent is to simply get a list of the most recent time items from these tables and the tables themselves are not related to each other, you would likely need to use a UNION.

```
$query = '(SELECT * FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM games)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10';
$r = mysql_query($query);
```

In this case, `date2` would not be ambiguous. Here you may actually be forced to specify the columns you want to select from each table if the tables do not have indentical columns/column types. The UNION will require that each SELECT statement return the same number of columns with the same data type in each column.

I also might suggest you start looking at using `mysqli` or `PDO` instead of deprecated `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: I want to list the most recently added content in order by the time stamp I have in each table. The time stamp is "date2" in each table.

Tables in the database I would like to use:
flash, games, jokes, pics, videos

They all use "date2" which is a time stamp. I would like for my homepage to list, in order by date2, all of them instead of how I currently have it split. So I guess I need to join/merge?

Comment: I don't believe I did this correctly. I have:
$r = mysql_query
(SELECT * FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM games)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10
or die(mysql_error()); 
& I received the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/content/t/a/g/tagt/html/homeallnew_content.php on line 11. Line 11 is, " (SELECT * FROM videos) "

Comment: @user3207931 That is just a syntax error.  I would suggest assigning the query string to a variable like `$query` and then doing `mysql_query($query)` to make you code more readable.  In your case though it looks like you a missing quotes around your string and have totally lost the parenthesis for `mysql_query()` call. See updated answer for how this should look.

Comment: You're the man! I ran into an error though & I guess Unions are picky. "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". After looking for an answer to this error it seems that Unions require, 
    The same number of columns in the SELECT clause &
    The column data type has to match at each position.

Comment: @user3207931 That is correct. That is why I mentioned in my answer that you might likely need to specifically select the fields you want returned. I probably was not explicit enough about this.

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense. I am trying my hardest to figure this out. I have this: $query = '(SELECT id, title, type, by, on, link, image, email, date2 FROM videos)
UNION
(SELECT id, title, type, by, on, link, image, email, date2 FROM pics)
ORDER BY date2 DESC
LIMIT 10';
$r = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()); --------- This was returned: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'by, on, link, image, email, date2 FROM videos) UNION (SELECT id, title, type, ' at line 1"

Comment: Actually it may be working. I removed a couple of the columns I was wanting to pull out (even though those columns were in all of the tables) it seems that it may be working. Thank you so much man!

Comment: Yeah man, I've got everything working smoothly now! I almost didn't post my question too. I'm glad I did! Thanks a lot to everyone who helped!!!

Answer (score 1):

Using a `LEFT JOIN` or other explicit join would be better here, but to the question in hand:

Disambiguate the table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM videos, games, pics ORDER BY videos.date2 DESC LIMIT 10
```